# Generating complex tables with Django

Tags: python, django, django-templates

While generating simple tables is really easy with django, I can't seem to figure out how to generate the complex table.

Currently my table is rendered with

```
<table class="table-striped table">
    {% for row in table %}
    <tr>
        {% for item in row %}
        <td>{{ item }}</td>
            {% endfor %}
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```

This works well with a 2 dimensional array, laying out the data in the way that is inserted into the table variable

However, generating complex tables is stumping me. Let's say I want to print a table with a header a string and a datetime, and a string and list for objects.

```
table = [
   ["value/key", Datetime]
   ["value 1", [Object, Object, Object]]
]
```

The objects are objects that need specific parsing.

[image: the table that is currently generated]

I need the list to be internally loopable, instead of it getting formatted to list notation, without the other objects changing appearance.

Comment: Could you elaborate the question? Why can't you add another `for` loop?

Comment: When running another for loop it'll iterate over regular strings. Besides, the objects will need very specific formatting, so I'd need some kind of type validation. I haven't seen anything in Django that can do that.

Comment: The question is quite vague. Please share the views and models you have used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a [new template filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-filters) that will take a value and render either the string or if it's a list, it'll render each item in the list.

```
# custom_filters.py
@register.filter(name='string_or_list')
def string_or_list(value, delimiter='\n'):
    """Renders string or each instance of a list with given delimiter."""
    if isinstance(value, list):
        return delimiter.join(value)
    return value
```

Then in your template you'd do:

```
{% load custom_filters %}
<table class="table-striped table">
    {% for row in table %}
    <tr>
        {% for item in row %}
            <td>{{ item|string_or_list }}</td>
        {% endfor %}
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```